# Why PyDev console says my __name__ is "builtins"?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm new to python programming. This is probably a dumb question but when I evaluate a file in the PyDev console and type in `__name__`, it returns `builtins` rather than `__main__`, which makes

```
if(__name__ == "__main__")
```

doesn't work. How to fix this?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like you did `del __name__` or something else that would clear the `__name__` global variable.

Comment: A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `__main__` when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt but I think PyDev console runs the script in a different way.

Comment: How do you run the script? It should be something like Run -> Run As -> Python Run

Comment: I didnt do anything like `del __name__`. Also as Trilliput mentioned, if I do Python Run directly, then `__name__` will be `__main__`, but I don't get an interactive console if I do so. I run my code by hitting Cmd+Option+Enter (I'm on a Mac) that gives me a dialog to create a console. The `__name__` in the console will return `__builtins__`.

Comment: Too late, but I think it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031968