# Why does print(__name__) give 'builtins'?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using pycharm.2017.1.2.
I installed anaconda2 with py3 environment.
in Pycharm, I'm using Python3 interpreter, and the code is simply:

```
print(__name__)
```

In Python console in Pycharm, it prints `builtins`.

If I click the 'run' button, it prints `main` as expected.

Why does the PyCharm Python console print `builtin` instead of `main`?

Comment: Wow, that's not the case in a normal Python console. Sorry that I don't know enough Pycharm to figure out why, I'd be interested in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm Python console is actually running a module called `pydevconsole.py` (should be located in C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py). This module creates an interpreter and sets it as an attribute to the `builtins` module.

Thus `print(__name__)` on PyCharm console will show `builtins`.

During execution (when you click 'run'), your specified Python interpreter is called, not the `pydevconsole` module. therefore `print(__name__)` shows `__main__` as expected.

Comment: thanks,but the code prints 'main' as wanted in another computer.So is it simply a pycharm setting problem and how to set it?

Comment: I believe you can change it in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Python Console. But I haven't adjusted these settings before. Also can you include the details of what your computer and the other computer show? For example, I see `C:\CorpApps\Python36\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 55520 55521
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 23 2017, 20:01:14) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> __name__
'builtins'` when I run the Python Console.

Comment: alright. the computer where prints 'builtins', the detail is `C:\Users\gpu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py3\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 58048 58049
` . the other computer printing 'main' as wanted,detail is `C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda2\envs\py3\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 5599 5600
`

Comment: i noticed that there is `Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 12:30:02) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 6.1.0
` below the details of the correct computer, but the wrong one does not contain the ipython information. Maybe it's the ipython problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the run environment is remote, and that IPython isn't installed. It's a [PyCharm issue reported here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31179). It happened in 2018.2 release, and a fix is in progress. To solve it just install IPython in the remote environment.